# How to change Modern Combat 5's ironsights

Tags: modern-combat-5-blackout

I play on a laptop and I'm too broke to get a mouse, so all I use is the track pad. The game only allows me to bind right-click to something else. I don't know how to bind ironsights to a key. Can anyone help?

Comment: Strangely, the in-game options allow rebinding keyboard controls but not mouse controls.